# osx terminal command to split text file into 2-column csv file

Tags: macos, csv, split, terminal

I have a text file and on each line there is at least one occurrence (normally more) of this text pattern:

```
<br>
```

So example line text would be:

```
textbefore<br>textafter<br>lasttext<br>
```

There can be multiple instances of the ',' character spread throughout the text.

As output, I want a valid 2-column comma separated text file.

The first column should be the text before the first `<br>`
The second column should be all the text after the first `<br>`

So neither column should contain this first `<br>`

How do I go about doing this using any tool available in OSX terminal?

Comment: Have edited question, not sure if what I mean is any clearer though. I guess I am asking if the two columns should both have double quotes around them so that any commas inside don't get read as column separators? And if that is true, how to add the quotes around the columns.

Comment: Yes u did understand what I was saying, thank you very much

Comment: Yes, solution worked well. Sorry for not accepting it previously, I didn't know how to do that. Having to click on greyed out question mark to accept is not intuitive to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Still not sure what you mean, but maybe this:

```
sed 's|^|"|; s|<[Bb][Rr]>|","|; s|$|"|' file
```

**Sample Output**

```
"textbefore","textafter<br>lasttext<br>"
```

That command says... *"Put double quotes at the start of every line. Replace the first `<br>` on the line with double quotes, comma, double quotes. Put double quotes at the end of every line."*

---

**Original Answer**

You can do that with `sed`:

```
sed 's|<br>|,|' yourFile
```

**Sample Output**

```
textbefore,textafter<br>lasttext<br>
```

Comment: How do I cope with the fact that there can be lots of ',' characters spread throughout the actual text?

Comment: @irantheworldforaday  Please show an example of what you mean and also how you expect it to be handled, by clicking `edit` under your original question.